# Kafka Streams Access the state store of a global KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Currently I am creating global ktables in my application for data enrichment.

```
final GlobalKTable<String, String> masterAssetTable = builder.globalTable(masterAssetTopic,
            Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("asset-master-store"));
```

Is there a way to programmatically access the backing global state store of this global KTable so that I can read values on demand like a cache?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a ReadOnlyKeyValueStore to access the data, some code snippets:

Let's say you have a GlobalKTable:

```java
streamsBuilder.globalTable(KafkaConfiguration.LEVERAGE_PRICE_TOPIC,
                        Materialized.<String, LeveragePrice, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(LEVERAGE_BY_SYMBOL_TABLE)
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                .withValueSerde(leveragePriceSerde));
```

You can then use the ReadOnlyKeyValuStore:

```java
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, LeveragePrice> leveragePriceView = streams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(LEVERAGE_BY_SYMBOL_TABLE, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
```

and expose a method to get any stored values:

```java
public LeveragePrice getLeveragePrice(String key) {
        return leveragePriceView.get(key);
    }
```

That would give you access to the values but in other scenarios you might need to access values using Kafka streams based on messages received from another input topic, in that case, you can add a processor or transform to your stream topology which also enables you to access the state store using `fetch` methods.

Comment: But if I am not wrong, this would give me a local statestore and not a global one. That is, I won't be able to access all the values in the store from all the instances of my application?

Comment: If you use a GlobalKTable doesn't matter how many instances of your application you have, every instance will read from all partitions for that topic so all values will be present in each local store on  any instances, that's basically the difference between a GlobalKTable and  a KTable(wich would have data from a single partition), This is well explained in official docs here -> https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams_concepts_globalktable